Require password only for administrative task
On my private Windows 11 Pro machine we share on local account for the whole family. It does not have any password.
For admin tasks like software installing, I have an administrator account which requires a password to protect my family from accidentally dangerous actions.
Is it possible to configure a local account with administrator privileges which

Does not ask for password when turn on the computer or unlock the screen
But prompts for password when you attempt to execute an elevated command


@Ramhound That's what I currently have. I like to know, how to configure the account with password but to be prompted only for privileged commands, i.e. when you use "Run as Administrator"

@Ramhound you may want to reread the question. To answer OP: No, if you create an admin account without password, and you log in with that account, whenever the user wants to install something, they get an UAC prompt, but given they already logged in, it will only have a yes and no prompt to make changes. Your current setup is the only way this works correctly.

Maybe it would be possible with 3rd party tools, e.g. PowerBroker from BeyondTrust or Microsoft Endpoint Privilege Management I use at work. But they are not for free and most likely an overkill for my private machine.

The setup you have is already this. You login with an account without password, and if you want to run anything that requires administrative privileges, you are required to enter a username and password. The only thing different is that you also need to specify a username, and if you have 2 users enabled on the computer, both users will show up at the Welcome screen. Auto logon can allow you to skip the welcome screen though, and the admin popup should remember the username from a previous session. Asking for a software recommendation is off-topic for SuperUser though.
